# Zend Gdata Calendar Bad Request Error

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp-1.3, gdata, gdata-api

I've been trying to work wit the ZEND GData API in CakePHP and have it setup and retreiving a list of calendars.

All of that works, however when I try to retrieve calendar events, I get a bad request error and I am not sure how to solve it. Here is the code followed by the error message received when the script is run.

***NOTE: I AM TESTING THIS FROM MY MACHINE USING XAMPP**

```
        //GET LIST OF EVENTS
        $index = 0;
        foreach($listFeed as $list) {
            $query = $service->newEventQuery($list->link[0]->href);
            // Set different query parameters
            $query->setUser('default');
            $query->setVisibility('private');
            $query->setProjection('full');
            $query->setOrderby('starttime');

            // Get the event list
            try {
                $eventFeed[$index] = $service->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
            } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getResponse() . "<br />";
            }
            $index++;
        }
```

Here is the error message:

> Error: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Mon, 14 May 2012 04:04:41 GMT Expires: Mon, 14 May 2012 04:04:41 GMT Cache-control: private, max-age=0 X-content-type-options: nosniff X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Connection: close Invalid request URI

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `$service->newEventQuery()` doesn't need a parameter here.
2. I believe you're retrieving calendar lists from a single user. Let's say it's yourself. So

   `$query->setUser('default');`

   won't help you get any second calendar, instead only the primary calendar which name is your email address.

   Refer from [Google developer protocol guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_protocol#RetrievingEvents%3a)

   To get a feed, you send the following HTTP request to Calendar, using the URL you found in the previous section of this document:

   `GET https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/userID/private-magicCookie/full`

   So replace userID with your calendarID to get a particular calendar's event feeds.

Try

```
    $index = 0;
    foreach($listFeed as $list) {
        $calendarID = $list->id->text;
        $user = str_replace("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full/", '', $calendarID);
        $query = $service->newEventQuery();
        // Set different query parameters
        $query->setUser($user);
        $query->setVisibility('private');
        $query->setProjection('full');
        $query->setOrderby('starttime');

        // Get the event list
        try {
            $eventFeed[$index] = $service->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
        } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getResponse() . "<br />";
        }
        $index++;
    }
```